# Merge neo4j relationships into one while returning the result if certain condition satisfies

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

My use case is:

I have to return whole graph in result but the condition is

- If there are more than 1 relationship in between two particular nodes in the same direction then I have to just merge it into 1 relationship. For ex: Lets say there are two nodes 'm' and 'n' and there are 3 relations in between these nodes say r1, r2, r3 (in the same direction) then when I get the result after firing cypher query I should get only 1 relation in between 'n' and 'm'.
- I need to perform some operations on top of it like the resultant relation that we got from merging all the relations should contain the properties and their values that I want to retain. Actually I will retain all the properties of any one of the relations that are merging depending upon the timestamp field that is one of the properties in relation.
- **Note :** I have same properties throughout all my relations (The number of properties and name of properties are same across all relations. Values may differ for sure)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

Delete all except the first

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH a,b,type(r) as type, collect(r) as rels
FOREACH (r in rels[1..] | DELETE r)
```

Ordering by timestamp first

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH a,r,b
ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC
WITH a,b,type(r) as type, collect(r) as rels
FOREACH (r in rels[1..] | DELETE r)
```

If you want to do all those operations virtually just on query results you'd do them in your programming language of choice.